# Jmeter>>> i found a error every time when i execute ./jmeter command(./jmeter: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java/bin/java: not found)

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, jmeter, ubuntu-16.04

I follow this link : `https://linuxhint.com/install_apache_jmeter_ubuntu/` for Jmeter installation but i found a error when i execute this line ./jmeter. >>

```
jmeter.sh: 99: [: Illegal number: 
./jmeter: 128: [: Illegal number: 
./jmeter: 199: ./jmeter: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java/bin/java: not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Then why you're asking questions here and not under that link?

Your [JAVA_HOME](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/820-7851/inst_cli_jdk_javahome_t/) and/or [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) environment variables are not correct, it's hard to say what's exactly wrong without seeing them so you need to double check their values and ensure that `java` executable is on your PATH

There are 5 simple steps to get JMeter up and running on Debian-based Linux distributions (including Ubuntu)

1. Update packages list:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update -qq
   ```
2. Install JRE 8 from [OpenJDK](https://openjdk.java.net/) project and [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/)

   ```
   apt-get install -y -qq openjdk-8-jre-headless wget > /dev/null
   ```
3. Download the [latest stable version](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) of JMeter:

   ```
   wget -q https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-5.3.tgz
   ```
4. Unpack it

   ```
   tar -xf apache-jmeter-5.3.tgz
   ```
5. Go to the "bin" folder of unpacked JMeter and check its version:

   ```
   cd apache-jmeter-5.3/bin/ && ./jmeter --version
   ```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [How to Get Started With JMeter: Installation & Test Plans](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-get-started-jmeter-installation-test-plans)